# DATETIME Error(Finding total days)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I want to find number of days:

```
int totalDays = (from d in db.RentalDvds.Where(d => d.ReturnedDate.HasValue && d.RentedDate.HasValue)
select (d.ReturnedDate - d.RentedDate).Days).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it gives the error

> Error 1   'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'Days' and no extension method 'Days' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

```
int totalDays = (
from d in db.RentalDvds
where d.ReturnedDate.HasValue &&  d.RentedDate.HasValue
select (d.ReturnedDate.Value - d.RentedDate.Value).Days).FirstOrDefault();
```

you need .Value if the type is nullable